# Brackets within a Regex string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match on a string. Brackets are special characters within regex, am I'm unsure of how'd i'd go about including them in my regex.

To provide more context, I want to find a string such as `test[test]`

My regex currently looks like this: `^*test[test]`. My expression is built out more much than this, but this example is enough to understand the problem.

How can i search for brackets in my string without triggering a character class. I need to use a regex, please don't recommend switching to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape a character with a backslash so `\[`

I can highly recommend https://regex101.com/ to test your regex without having to code it.

Try: `^.*test\[test\]` - This mean `{start of line}`, `{anything}`, `"test[test]"`.

Comment: Tried this already and unfortunately didnt work

Comment: @Hysii ... what _exactly_ did you try? ... If you used the link offered here to try, you can save what was attempted, and post that link here, so that others can use that as a reference.

Comment: ```^``` is start of line. ```*``` is your problem. That means match the previous thing 0 or many times. Usually you see ```.*``` meaning any number of any single character, but ```^*``` is not valid. Try ```^.*test\[test\]``` if you want to match: the start of a line, anything, then ```test[test]```

Comment: @paul-t queried my live data set. Can't really share the results of that

Comment: @Hysii ... that's fine, but can you not create a sample equivalent of bogus/dummy data that still meets the desired goal?

Comment: @james mysql interprets them the same

Comment: @Hysii ... does [this example](https://regex101.com/r/jOHeTR/1) help?